# use vuejs variable in pure javascript file

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm practicing laravel with vuejs and I'm wondering if possible to use vuejs (component) variable in other file with pure javascript.
I created my.js and registered it in app.js.

```
require('./my.js');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

In my.js I have following code.

```
alert(app.name)
```

**name** is variable used in vuejs component. As a result I received alert undefined. Please give me some guidelines.

Comment: Though I'm not familiar with Vue, I'm pretty sure that you can pass `app` to `my.js` or export your alert as a function and then call it in `app.js`. Either way, you will need to reconfigure a bit.

Comment: Can you try moving `require()` to underneath?

Comment: @senty Yes, but problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

You must run the code in the correct order:

```js
function MyFunc(vm) {
  alert(vm.name)
}

const app = new Vue({
  data: {
    name: 'FooBar'
  }
});

MyFunc(app)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

---

### Example 1

**my.js**:

```js
export default function(vm) {
  alert(vm.name);
}
```

**main.js**:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import MyFunc from './my';

const app = new Vue({
  data: {
    name: 'FooBar'
  }
});

MyFunc(app)
```

---

### Example 2

**my.js**:

```js
export default (app) => alert(app.name);
```

**vue.js**:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

export default new Vue({
  data: {
    name: 'FooBar'
  }
});
```

**main.js**:

```js
import bar from './vue'
import foo from './my'

foo(bar)
```